# Jquery animate object, then create other objects based of new margin-left

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-animate, append, margin

So, I have an object that can be animated (lets call this obj1). Other objects can be dynamically created before or after the animation, so I want their margin-left position to be based off obj1's current margin-left.

this is the relevant snippet of code. The weird thing is it works with the alerts in, but if I take out the alerts the margin-left will default to what was originally in the style sheet. The Timeout is to insure that the new obj isn't created until the previous obj is finished animating to it's new position.

```
if(!rounds.match12) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    createMatchup(matchups[6].winner, matchups[7].winner, 12, false); //this creates a new matchup and appendsTo current container
    var pos = $('#matchup5').css('margin-left');
    alert(pos);
    $('#matchup12').css('margin-left' , pos);
    alert($('#matchup12').css('margin-left'));
    $('#matchup12').css('margin-left' , '-=195');
    alert($('#matchup12').css('margin-left'));
    rounds.match12 = true;
    },1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code my guess would be that your timeout is most likely not firing in sync with the animation. jQuery animations are not always exact and a millisecond difference between it and your timeout and it can fail or provide inconsistant values. Try using the [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback instead of your timeout as follows:

```
// replace 'fast' with a millisecond timeout if desired //
$('selector').animate(marginLeft: 'X', 'fast', function(){
    // dynamically create and position new elements here
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately that won't work for me. The animation is kind of it's own function which can be applied to multiple things. The creation of the new objects aren't necessarily related to the animation. I really just want the new objects margin left to be based off the other objects left.

Comment: @user1310774 Can you create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net with your code as this helps us provide an answer.

Comment: I kinda fixed it I had css transition on the containing element which seemed to then conflict with changing the margins for some reason.